# How can I make a text input using lwjgl?

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl

I am trying to change over from swing to LWJGL for reasons unknown, and wanted to know how to make a text box input thing. Like the JTextField or something. If anyone could tell me how to, that would be wonderful.

Thank you very much,
Howard Stark

Answer (score 0):

For text input in LWJGL I recommend you use [TWL](http://twl.l33tlabs.org/) or [NiftyGUI](http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/). This are libraries that will allow you to render GUI elements.